# How to copy URL with page title from Safari to Pages

Tags: applescript, safari, pages, url

In earlier versions of Safari and Pages drag&drop of an URL from Safari to Pages resulted in a link with the page title as the text, and the URL as a link "behind" it. It still works that way in Mail in Mojave.

But with Safari and Pages all you get with drag&drop is a link (without the page title), which you then need to edit to replace the displayed text with i.e. the page title.

Is there a way (maybe via AppleScript) to insert title & URL of a Safari tab into a Pages document without having to manually edit it afterwards?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! I did a rather heavy-handed edit to focus your question on the topic at hand. In case I missed something please just edit it back in.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution, with the *current tab* of the *front window* of **Safari** set to the desired *address*, one would then in **Pages** press a *keyboard shortcut* to, at the *cursors present location*, create a *website link* matching the documents style (font size, etc,) having the **Title** and **URL** of the **Safari** *target* pasted into the **Pages** document.

Off the top of my head, if that's even doable, it would probably require using **AppleScriptObjC**, which unfortunately is not something I know how to do, rather than using *plain vanilla basic* **AppleScript**.

That said, let me offer an *example* that works for me in **macOS High Sierra** and **Pages 7.1**.

Using an **Automator** *service*<sup>1</sup> with a **Run AppleScript** *action*, set for **Pages**, and assigning it a *keyboard shortcut* in **System Preference** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, creates a *website link* on its own *line* directly after the *line* the *cursor* is on when the *keyboard shortcut* is pressed.

With this particular *code*, it needs to be done in this manner; however, one can then *cut* and *paste* it where desired in the document and remove the extra *line* added to the document. It's not the ideal solution, but it does get the job done with the least amount of hassle while using this particular method.

- In **Automator**, create a new **Service**<sup>1</sup>, setting: **Service receives** [no input] **in** [Pages]

  - <sup>1</sup> In **macOS Mojave**, an **Automator** *service* is now called a **Quick Action**.
- Add a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the *default code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below.
- Save the **Automator** *service* as, e.g.,: **Add Safari Weblink to Pages**
- In **System Preference** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > e.g. **Add Safari Weblink to Pages**, assign it a *keyboard shortcut*, e.g.,: **^⌘L** (Control-Command-L)

  - Note: I wanted the least number of *keys* to press and something close to the *default* **⌘K**, and **^⌘L** was it. It also does not step on any other *default keys* in **Pages**.
- In **Pages**, with a document opened, press **^⌘L** to create the *website link* of the *current tab* of the *frontmost* **Safari** *window*.

**With a little practice, the following *steps* will become second nature:**

- Select the target *webpage* in **Safari**, letting it be the *frontmost* **Safari** *window*.
- In **Pages**, with a document opened, *press*:

  - **^⌘L**, and wait until **Add Link** pop-up dialog disappears.
  - **⌘X**
  - **delete** <sub>(Removes the added line.)</sub>
  - Set the *cursor* to where you want the *website link* inserted.
  - **⌘C**
- This should only take but a few seconds total.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
if not running of application "Safari" then return

tell application "Safari" to set |Title & URL| to {name, URL} of current tab of front window
delay 0.1

set the clipboard to first item of |Title & URL| -- Title of front Safari document.
delay 0.1

tell application "Pages"
    activate
    delay 0.1
    if name of front window is in {"Choose a Template", ""} then return
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    key code 124 using {command down} -- Right Arrow Key - Send cursor to end of line.
    delay 0.1
    key code 36 -- Enter Key - Send cursor to beginning of new line.
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "v" using {option down, shift down, command down} -- Paste and Match Style. (Title of front Safari document.)
    delay 0.1
    key code 123 using {shift down, command down} -- Left Arrow Key - Highlight pasted Title.
    delay 0.1
    tell current application to set the clipboard to second item of |Title & URL| -- URL of front Safari document.
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "k" using {command down} -- Pages > Format > Add Link > Webpage -- (When some text is highlighted.)
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "v" using {command down} -- Paste (URL of front Safari document.)
    delay 0.1
    key code 36 -- Enter Key - Needed to set pasted URL, otherwise it stays as the default URL.
    delay 0.1
    key code 53 -- Escape Key - Dismiss the Add Link pop up dialog box.
end tell

set the clipboard to ""
```

- **Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* makes use of the **Clipboard** in order to use **Paste and Match Style** in the **Pages** document, and then clears the **Clipboard**. Keep this in mind so as not to loose something that's there and nowhere else if applicable. Additionally, if the *length* of **Title** exceeds the *length* of the *line* it's pasted to, only the last *line* of the pasted **Title** will be *highlighted* when the *website link* is created. This is one of the drawbacks of using just *plain vanilla basic* **AppleScript** verses **AppleScriptObjC**.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans, `if not running of application "Safari" then return` **and** `if name of front window is in {"Choose a Template", ""} then return`, it does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

You might also find that the *value* of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command*, in some instances, may need to be adjusted for use on your system, adjust as/if necessary.

---

[image: Add Safari Weblink to Pages]

Answer (score 1):

A general solution is to combine your AppleScript (Script Editor)(`/System/Applications/Utilities/Script Editor.app`)  with an app launcher like [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com).

### Script

```
tell application "Safari" to tell document 1
    set the clipboard to "[#]: " & URL & " \"" & name & "\""
end tell
```

In this case, the result string is formatted as the second part of a Markdown reference-style link. E.g.:

```markdown
[link text][1]

[1]: url "title"
```

### Hotkey Trigger

1. In your app launcher, create a hotkey workflow
2. In [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com), click `Settings > Workflows`, then click `+ > Blank workflow`
3. Add a `Workflow Name`; other values are optional
4. Click `+ > Triggers > Hotekey`

   1. In the `Hotkey Settings` tab, assign a `Hotkey` value. E.g. `⌥C`
   2. Leave `Action` as `Pass through to workflow` or your launcher's equivalent
   3. Leave `Argument` set to `None`.
   4. Go to the `Related Apps` tab
   5. Verify `have focus` is the value assigned to `Hotkey is...active when..apps`
   6. Click `Save`
5. Click `+ Actions > Run Script`
6. Set `Language` to `/usr/bin/osascript (AS)`; leave other options set to their default values
7. Paste your version of the above script into the `Script` box
8. Click `Save`
9. Drag the `Hotkey` box's node and connect it to the `Run Script` box

That's it! Now clicking `⌥C` in Safari lets you paste URL and title values in any app in any format with the standard `Paste` keyboard shortcut — **`⌘P`**.

As above, you should be able to run your script as a service. You can assign a shortcut key to run the service by going to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Services`.

PS: You can also download my Alfred Workflow and scripts (plain text and .scpt) from [GitHub](https://github.com/ssent1/misc/tree/master/scripts/curl).

Comment: This workflow finally give me the chance to stop using Chrome because I'm constantly sharing url with title.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, I wanted to copy the page title, so to solve it I made an Automator Quick Action which appears in Safari's Safari->Services menu. It gets the page title and puts it in the clipboard. It probably could be improved to also get the link. Note the "no input" choice.

[image]

[image]

```
tell application "Safari"
    set mytitle to name of current tab in window 1
end tell

return mytitle
```

I got the Apple Script from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42476096/259521).